# Test data on next record

Tags: mainframe, syncsort

I would like to know if is is possible to read the next record when we are using SyncSORT (SyncTool) based on a certain condition.

Example of the input

Sort key will be account nbr + descending record type + amount

```
account nbr  amount  record type
11111111111   10      reversal    not in the output
11111111111   10      deposit     not in the output
33333333333   20      deposit     in the output
44444444444   15      deposit     in the output
55555555555   20      reversal    in the output
55555555555   10      deposit     in the output
66666666666   30      reversal    in the output no match
```

When a reversal type is read, a deposit should follow with the same amount, in this case it both record the reversal and deposit should not be in the output file.   It is possible the amount is not the same for the reversal and the deposit, in this case both records should be in the output file.

output

```
33333333333   20      deposit
44444444444   15      deposit
55555555555   20      reversal   
55555555555   10      deposit     
66666666666   30      reversal
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As long as your SyncSORT is up-to-date enough.

You need to use JOINKEYS. Specify the same DSN for both input datasets, and indicate that they are SORTED. There is an undocumented feature which allows the use of JNFnCTNL files, like DFSORT.

In JNF1CNTL (which is a "preprocessor" for the first JOINKEYS dataset) temporarily add a sequence number to each record. The default is that the sequence starts at one. Here it is useful to be explicit...

Because, in JNF2CNTL you want to do the same thing, but start the sequence at zero (START=0).

The key for each of the JOINKEYS is the sequence number.

Use JOIN UNPAIRED,F1. Define a REFORMAT with all the data from the first file, and data for comparison from the second file.

This is what a four-record dataset would look like if you imagine the join:

```
- - A 0
A 1 B 1
B 2 C 2
C 3 D 3
D 3 - -
```

Because you specify JOIN UNPAIRED,F1 you won't actually see the mismatched A 0 (because that is on F2) but you will see the mismatched D 3.

If you look at your REFORMAT record, you now have data from the "current" record, and data from the "next" record.

Then there's a little more work to select only the records you want. But, dinner first...

Comment: Hi Bill, thanks for your answer. Do you have any example of this somewhere in the (ibm icetool documentation or syncsort) ?   It will be great to not have to code this in COBOL !!!